# DLL Project doesn't generate .exp and .lib file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

So, I have a c++ solution which contains 3 project ( 2 DLL, and 1 .exe).

here's the basic dependencies representation:

Application --> DLL2

Application --> DLL1

DLL2 --> DLL1

The problem I have is that DLL2 (when building it) does generate the .dll but doesn't generate the .lib and .exp I need to reference properly DLL2 in the Application project. However, DLL1 does generate these files and I've compared DLL1's settings to DLL2's, and I can't find what the difference could be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that DLL2 had only .h files and no content in any of the associated .cpp files. So the IDE didn't see the neccesity of creating the .lib file.

Comment: thanks this answer helped me. also i have to add at least one `static __declspec(dllexport)` method to make `lib` file appear

Comment: Unlike Unix/Linux creating shared libraries in WIndows is a *MAJOR* PITA.
The token "extern" is not sufficient to force the  compiler/linker to tag a function for inclusion in to the DLL.  Why Microsoft implemented things this way I'm sure has some logical reason.  I suspect it employs hundreds if not thousands to explain why the "__declspec ( dllimport )/__declspec( dllexport)" tokens need to be staffed.
Or alternatly pepole can be hired to go through developers code and make sure that *.def files are insync with the latest code.

Answer (score 14):

The simple explanation for that is that you just forgot to export anything.  The linker won't create a .lib/.exp file if there are no exports.  You can verify this by running `dumpbin.exe /exports` on the DLL.  With the expectation that you see nothing.

Use `__declspec(dllexport)` to export symbols from the DLL.  Or a .def file.

Comment: And remember to include the headers that define the usual export macro. :)

Comment: Yes... unfortunatly the token "extern" isn't enough to tag something for dll import.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered another way to cause the same thing to happen. I moved some routines that I developed and tested as service routines in another DLL into a DLL of their own. Since this move was planned before I wrote the first line of code, they weren't marked for export, and were, hence, using that project's default calling convention, __cdecl. When I built the library, the build environment didn't create a .LIB file. After some investigation, and inspired by the mention of __declspec(dllimport) in this topic, I realized that, although I moved the declarations into the template header file generated by the New Project Wizard, I forgot to insert the name of the generated calling convention macro into the prototypes.

With the calling convention specified, both in the header and the CPP files that hold the implementations, I got the expected .LIB file.